# jQuery: Binding same event to window and another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

How do I bind the same event to `window` and as well as on another element at one go. I tried this, but it does not work for me:

```
$('window, #someId').bind('click', doSomething);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you copy/paste an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Although I agree that the snippet I have given is a bad example, I generally wanted to find out how to do something like above without making two separate bind calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#someId').add(window).bind('click', doSomething);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Well `window` isn't an element. You can bind an event to the `<body>`:

```
$('body, #someId').bind('click', doSomething);
```

When you do this, you'll notice that your handler gets clicks from all over the place.  Why?  Because all those clicks will "bubble up" to the body anyway. Thus you'll have to check in the handler what the "target" attribute is of the event, and only respond to the event if the target is the element registered:

```
$('body, #someId').click(function(ev) {
  if (this === ev.target) {
    // do stuff
    ev.stopPropagation(); // optional
  }
  else {
    // event not relevant
  }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/Gg76K/) is an illustrative jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).add('#someId').bind('click', doSomething);
```